# ～そばから and its する form

Tags: grammar

Why does [this site](http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=3730) say that そばから "Can be used only with past tense" then use it with ている？

[image]

The usage note:

> 後件は良くないことが多く、**過去のことにしか使えません**。

The example sentence:

> 雪かきをするそばから雪が積もり始めている。

Comment: I have edited your question to include the important parts so that people don't have to squint at a blurry image. Please consider making it as easy as possible for people to help you.

Comment: I think it is just a mistake. It may be better to visit the お問い合わせ page linked from the right column and ask the site owner.

Comment: Not a mistake. Other Japanese sites also say it can be used with 辞書形 or た形, just that the latter is far more common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't say "past tense" but 過去のこと and it seems to mean "what has already happened", here. It's certainly misleading, though.